# Build gradle system app as part of AOSP build

Tags: android, makefile, android-gradle-plugin, android-source

I have a custom rom based on AOSP and I am working on a system app that is packaged during the rom build just like any other system app.

Is it possible to switch this app to a gradle style app and build that specific app with gradle during the AOSP build? i.e. - Start the gradle build from a makefile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't find a perfect solution for this. But you can try:

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
$(info $(shell ($(LOCAL_PATH)/gradlew build -p $(LOCAL_PATH)/)) )
$(info $(shell ($(LOCAL_PATH)/finalize.sh $(PRODUCT_OUT))))
```

finallize.sh:

```
BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
PRODUCT_PATH=$1
echo $PRODUCT_PATH
java -Xmx1024m -jar $BASEDIR/../../../out/host/linux-x86/framework/signapk.jar $BASEDIR/../../../build/target/product/security/platform.x509.pem $BASEDIR/../../../build/target/product/security/platform.pk8 $BASEDIR/main/build/outputs/apk/main-normal-release-unsigned.apk $PRODUCT_PATH/system/app/MYAPP.apk
```

It worked for me

Comment: This script runs when including the android.mk file, and I have my suspicions that this is the incorrect time for it to run (compared to when an app using BUILD_PACKAGE will be built).

Comment: is there any better solution by now?

Comment: @phoebus No, no any better solution, I wasted half day to find a better solution, e.g. find a script tool to convert the gradle building files to Android.mk, but I fail, so the current answer is: NO.