# Include CMake project in AOSP build

Tags: android-ndk, cmake, android-source

I have a android-ndk based app, which is built with cmake, and I want to integrate that project into an AOSP-build and have it included in the resulting android image. However there seems to be no possibility to directly start a cmake build in the AOSP build system.

For example in the android-7.1.1._r35 source tree, the zlib-external has a CMakeLists.txt, but additionally an Android.mk file, which seems to actually be used for compilation with AOSP instead of cmake. The build instructions are duplicated in both files:

```
external/zlib/src/CMakeLists.txt
external/zlib/Android.mk
```

Since the project has quite a lot of source files (~1500 cpps), I'm trying to avoid the tedious task of converting and maintaining an extra build system.

Is it possible to invoke a cmake build from the Android.mk based build system or do I have to write an Android.mk file to build my app? If cmake can be called, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to build cmake projects in the AOSP build system.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Do you per chance know anything about future plans to integrate CMake functionality into the build system?

Comment: No plans. That's generally not the approach we take in AOSP. The system works a lot better if we just rewrite build files in our own build language rather than trying to mix and match a handful of different build systems into one build.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, in case someone stumbles upon this in the future: There seems to be a solution, though it's hacky - see [Build gradle system app as part of AOSP build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898340/build-gradle-system-app-as-part-of-aosp-build) for reference. This solution seems to work, but the gradle/cmake build is started directly when the makefiles are parsed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a shell script to run cmake and make command
2. invoke the shell script in Android.mk file, like：

   ```
   SHELL_RESULT := $(shell ($(LOCAL_PATH)/run_cmake.sh))
   ```